# select option filtering not working properly

Tags: jquery

Im trying to filter out other values what doesnt contain same text.

If log console then I can see there is 5 times -1 and the one 6 and then 3 times -1 again

So that 6 means it found but it didnt select it..

```js
let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix'); //KO
let t = $('.booked-appointment-details > .appointment-title').text(); //Prime Studio
let a = t+' - #'+n; // Prime Studio - #KO
console.log(a)
    //in select option I have $450 - Prime Studio - #KO but it won't select
let titleValue = $(".field-paid-service-select option").filter((i, e) => {
    console.log(e.innerHTML.indexOf(a)); // 5 -1 // 6 // 3 -1
    return e.innerHTML.indexOf(a) > -1;
}).val();

$(".field-paid-service-select").val(titleValue).attr("disabled", true);
//$(".field-paid-service-select").find('option').not(':selected').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="change_service_booked">
    <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP" selected="selected">Party</option>
  <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">Schools</option>
  <option class="level-0" data-prefix="EV">Business</option>
</select>

<div class="booked-appointment-details">
  <p class="appointment-title">Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio</p>
</div>

<select data-calendar-id="0" class="field-paid-service-select" name="paid-service-label---4681606">
        <option value>Select a Product</option>
<option value="1860">330 € - TalTech leiutajate stuudio – #SP</option><option value="1858">330 € - Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio – #SP</option><!-- Superangeli Stuudio – #SP --><option value="1859">330 € - Superangeli Stuudio – #SP</option><!-- Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #SP --><option value="1857">330 € - Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #SP</option><!-- TalTech leiutajate stuudio – #EV --><option value="1856">480 € - TalTech leiutajate stuudio – #EV</option><!-- Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio – #EV --><option value="1855">480 € - Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio – #EV</option><!-- Superangeli Stuudio – #EV --><option value="1854">480 € - Superangeli Stuudio – #EV</option><!-- Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #EV --><option value="1853">480 € - Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #EV</option><!-- TalTech leiutajate stuudio – #KO --><option value="1852">250 € - TalTech leiutajate stuudio – #KO</option><!-- Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio – #KO --><option value="1851">250 € - Tallinna Ülikooli nutistuudio – #KO</option><!-- Superangeli Stuudio – #KO --><option value="1841">250 € - Superangeli Stuudio – #KO</option><!-- Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #KO --><option value="1758">250 € - Tartu Ülikooli Avastuudio – #KO</option>       </select>
```

Comment: provide more code there is more questions than answers. Where is select? How looks like?

Comment: In the question editor, the body wysiwyg editor, the icon button to the right of the `insert image` button is the `code snippet` button. Create a live snippet of your issue with demo HTML or your question will get closed man.

Comment: @joshmoto Added snippet. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. You are trying to conditionally filter options in your `.field-paid-service-select` select field by html value based on current `#change_service_booked` selected option? Is this right?

Comment: Could the `.field-paid-service-select` select options have the prefix also as a data option or are you forced to use the option html string to filter by?

Comment: I have only 8 + 1 (Select a product) options for `.field-paid-service-select` and each option has `price` and `name` and `prefix`. In my system first user selects `#change_service_booked` then he sees services in list and clicks `book` then opens modal where is `.appointment-title` and select option what it should select automatically because I try to hide other options and disable this field.

Comment: So if other options doesnt contain `Prime Studio - #KO` then it selects `Prime Studio - #KO` and hides other options and disables field.

Answer (score 0):

OK not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve? Let me know if I'm going off track.

My code is probably not the most efficient way to achieve conditional logic on your select options, but my answer might get feedback and better answers posted for your question :-)

See comments in code to know whats going on.

```js
// on ready
$(function() {

  // get our current change service booked selected prefix from option data attr
  let prefix = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix'); //KO
  
  // show and hide field paid service select options based on current selected service booked option
  show_hide_paid_service_select_options(prefix);

  // on service booked select change via input event
  $('#change_service_booked').on('input', function(e) {

    // get new selected option data prefix
    prefix = $(this).find(':selected').data('prefix');

    // re run the show and hide field paid service select function passing our new prefix
    show_hide_paid_service_select_options(prefix);

  });

});

// show and hide field paid service select function passing prefix as first param
function show_hide_paid_service_select_options(prefix) {

  // first option found default as true
  let first_found = true;

  // each field paid service select options (param i as index)
  $('.field-paid-service-select option').each(function(i) {

    // if the prefix chars and preceding hash # char match at the end of option text 
    if (new RegExp(`#${prefix}$`).test($(this).text())) {
    
      // if first option found
      if(first_found) {
      
        // log option text
        console.log($(this).text());
      
        // make this option selected using prop
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
        
        // set first option found to false
        first_found = false;
      
      }

      // show matching option
      $(this).show();

    } else {
    
      // hide matching option
      $(this).hide();

    }

  });

}
```

```css
SELECT {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="change_service_booked">
  <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
  <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO" selected="selected">Schools</option>
  <option class="level-0" data-prefix="EV">Business</option>
</select>

<select data-calendar-id="0" class="field-paid-service-select" name="paid-service-label---7876891">
  <option value="">Select a Product</option>
  <option value="17">$1777 - Ulikoli nutistudio - #EV</option>
  <option value="18">$999 - Ulikoli Avastudio - #EV</option>
  <option value="19">$2494 - Superangeli Studio - #EV</option>
  <option value="12">$880 - Superangeli Studio - #SP</option>
  <option value="13">$450 - Prime Studio - #KO</option>
  <option value="14">$750 - Ulikoli nutistudio - #SP</option>
  <option value="15">$20 - Leiutajate studio - #SP</option>
  <option value="16">$660 - Leiutajate studio - #EV</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code wont work because you try find by only `prefix`. But if you check there is 4 same `prefix` but different studio room. I need exact same studio what is in `.appointment-title`

Comment: Update code, not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: Sorry didn't actually repost my answer will re-do it again